# El significado de la palabra "flaca"

Tags: modismos

Sé que hay muchos significados para la palabra en cada país
hispanohablante. ¿Qué significa la palabra [*flaca*](http://www.musica.com/letras.asp?letra=37302) en este contexto? :

> ```
> Flaca no me claves
> tus puñales
> por la espalda
> tan profundo
> no me duelen
> no me hacen mal
> Lejos
> en el centro
> ```

Esta canción que fue compuesta por el cantante argentino Andres Calamaro.

Answer (score 3):

*Flaca*, en ese contexto, es una forma coloquial y amistosa de referirse a una chica. Puede ser una amiga o una chica de la que no sabes el nombre. Normalmente se usa con connotación de piropo (Flaca = guapa, buena figura)

Cierto es que se usa sobre todo en Argentina, pero el cantante catalán Pau Donés (del grupo Jarabe de Palo) se hizo famoso por un primer éxito titulado ['La Flaca'](http://www.musica.com/letras.asp?letra=59473).

Cierto es que en la mayoría de los otros dialectos puede no tener las connotaciones que tiene en Argentina. En España no es tan común oír "flaca" para referirse a una chica (Nota, yo en ocasiones he visto usar "gordita" para referirse a una chica. A pesar que pueda ser usado de forma cariñosa este término tiene obvias connotaciones peyorativas).

Comment: Esa canción usa intencionadamente algunas expresiones latinoamericanas (como *tomar* por *beber*); además, en la letra se ve claramente que *la flaca* está excesivamente delgada, mientras que en el uso argentino no tiene por qué ser así.

Comment: @Gorpik, completamente cierto, sólo apunto que el éxito de esa canción ayudó a popularizar el término al otro lado del charco. El resto del post explica el significado de la expresión.

Comment: En eso estoy de acuerdo, pero creo que era importante señalar que la canción, pese a ser española, está compuesta (letra y música) en un estilo caribeño.

Answer (score 2):

En este contexto (es decir, usada como vocativo en una canción escrita por un argentino), la palabra *flaca* es, simplemente, un apelativo cariñoso. En Argentina se puede usar tanto para hombres (*flaco*) como mujeres delgadas y tiene una connotación generalmente positiva, aunque no necesariamente.

En otros países, en cambio, tiene connotaciones más negativas. En España, por ejemplo, si dices que una chica está *flaca* quieres decir que está excesivamente delgada. En Argentina, podrías usar la palabra *reflaca* para lo mismo.

Answer (score 0):

As ChangoLaton said, it is a term of endearment. However it is mostly used in Argentina (where Calamaro is from), in other parts of Latinamerica the opposite is sometimes used (mostly for males though); "gordo".

Comment: Not quite. 'Gorda' --and its diminutive 'gordita'-- is a term of endearment from a husband to a wife in Colombia and Venezuela at the least.

Answer (score 0):

En este contexto, o sea la canción, **flaca** vendría a significar **ex-enamorada** o alguien por quien se sintió algo en su momento pero ahora no te presta atención.

Answer (score 0):

"Flaca" puede usarse en muchos contextos. En el caso de la canción, pienso que la está llamando por la forma cómo siempre la llamó de cariño, como también pudo ser "Lola", "Gordita", "Mi amor", o cualquier variante.

Por ejemplo si haces el cambio:

```
Lola no me claves
tus puñales
por la espalda
tan profundo
no me duelen
no me hacen mal
```

El sentido sigue siendo el mismo.